# cp fails with 'Resource busy'

Tags: permissions, mount, ssd, darwin

I store RAW images (DNG) and my Apple Photos library on an external SSD (Rarely used, 1 year old).

Some files (approx. 2-5%) are corrupted. I face the following behavior:

```
Copy via Finder: Error 'File is in use'
Copy via cp: 'Resource busy'
Details:
   OS: macOS 12.1 (21C52)
   uname -a: Darwin 21.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 21.2.0: Sun Nov 28 20:29:10 PST 2021; root:xnu-8019.61.5~1/RELEASE_ARM64_T8101 arm64
   ls -la <filename>: -rwxrwxrwx  1 <my user> <my group>
   sudo lsof | grep <filename>: shows nothing
   sudo fs_usage | grep <filename>: shows nothing
```

I can copy files after compressing (zip) on the SSD.
I mounted the drive in read-only mode, same behavior.

Further, RAW images show curved lines in preview and FastRawViewer. The Photos.sqlite file from the Apple Photos library cannot be copied too, but I can open it using the Apple Photos App: [image: Corrupted image]

What can I do to copy the files and what is the cause?

Comment: that looks like storage failure. And, if you have more than one file with such "stripey" problems, it's unlikely it's due to some corruption due to software bugs, unclean removal etc, but actual SSD-level failure.

Comment: Thank you, @MarcusMüller. As I can open them, the files can be read. Do you know a way to copy them? I guess some meta data is indicating wrongly the OS, that the files are being modified at the moment.